# how can I calculate $r$ in $r + r^2 + r^3 + r^4 = 100$?

Tags: problem-solving

As the title says, I want to know how to solve this equation. Just cannot find a way

I want to know how much % profit someone has to make EVERY MONTH in average from a stock within $4$ months, to double the money. In other words: I have to make r % profit on every single month of the 4 month to double (r=100%) the money.

Comment: What is $r^5 -1 $ ?

Comment: Anyway you need to solve a polynomial that has degree more than $2$.

Comment: Clearly, $2<r<3$. So $r\simeq 2.84922$.

Comment: thanks guys. for me as a math noob, can you show me the exact way? I have also changed the description of my question to what my goal is with this equation.

Comment: You can factor, but then to find the actual solutions you must use newtons method

Comment: You need to reformulate the whole question, including the title and the tag. Are we discussing the profit, or are we discussing the equation? This may not be the same.

Comment: @Johnny Your equation has  a very ugly real root. If you want I can explain how to solve a fourth degree  polynomial equation in the general case with another example of polynomial, which has human's roots.

Comment: Add 1 to both side, left side is a geometric progression , so we have: (r^5 - 1)/(r - 1) = 101 ; so we have r(101 - r^4) = 101, r = 2 gives 170 for lef side, r=3 gives 60 for left side, so 2 < r < 3. By trial and error you can find r approximately.

Comment: I don't think that equation does what you want.

Comment: If you started with one dollar, then after a month you'd have $1+r$ dollars, and then $(1+r)^2$ dollars. So you want $(1+r)^4=2$, ro $r=\sqrt[4]{2}-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying problem is that you've got the wrong equation.

If you make a profit of $r$% after each month, and started with $n$, then after one month, you'd have $n\left(1+\frac{r}{100}\right)$, after two months, $n\left(1+\frac{r}{100}\right)^2$, and in general, after $m$ months:

$$n\left(1+\frac{r}{100}\right)^m$$

When $m=4,$ you want to have $2n$, so you want:

$$\left(1+\frac{r}{100}\right)^4=2$$

which yields:

$$r=100(\sqrt[4]2-1)\approx 18.92$$

Comment: Thanks Thomas!! This helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to know something like this:
$$
-1/4-1/12\,\sqrt {3}\sqrt {{\frac {4\, \left( 2260+6\,\sqrt {48382278}
 \right) ^{2/3}-5\,\sqrt [3]{2260+6\,\sqrt {48382278}}-4808}{\sqrt [3]
{2260+6\,\sqrt {48382278}}}}}+1/12\,\sqrt {6}\sqrt {{\frac {-2\,\sqrt 
{{\frac {4\, \left( 2260+6\,\sqrt {48382278} \right) ^{2/3}-5\,\sqrt [
3]{2260+6\,\sqrt {48382278}}-4808}{\sqrt [3]{2260+6\,\sqrt {48382278}}
}}} \left( 2260+6\,\sqrt {48382278} \right) ^{2/3}+15\,\sqrt {3}\sqrt 
[3]{2260+6\,\sqrt {48382278}}-5\,\sqrt [3]{2260+6\,\sqrt {48382278}}
\sqrt {{\frac {4\, \left( 2260+6\,\sqrt {48382278} \right) ^{2/3}-5\,
\sqrt [3]{2260+6\,\sqrt {48382278}}-4808}{\sqrt [3]{2260+6\,\sqrt {
48382278}}}}}+2404\,\sqrt {{\frac {4\, \left( 2260+6\,\sqrt {48382278}
 \right) ^{2/3}-5\,\sqrt [3]{2260+6\,\sqrt {48382278}}-4808}{\sqrt [3]
{2260+6\,\sqrt {48382278}}}}}}{\sqrt [3]{2260+6\,\sqrt {48382278}}
\sqrt {{\frac {4\, \left( 2260+6\,\sqrt {48382278} \right) ^{2/3}-5\,
\sqrt [3]{2260+6\,\sqrt {48382278}}-4808}{\sqrt [3]{2260+6\,\sqrt {
48382278}}}}}}}}
$$

when numerical solution will give you $2.849217207$ approximately.

---

Edit:

But in all seriousness you must factor and then use alternative methods such a Newton Raphson to solve for the zeroes. Otherwise its virtually impossible by just hand

Comment: I lol'd so hard

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. So generally, is the way I want to go the right way to solve the problem as I've written in the description? "I want to know how much % profit someone has to make EVERY MONTH in average from a stock within 44 months, to double the money." In other words: I have to make r % profit on every single month of the 4 month to double (r=100%) the money.

Comment: No, you are not going the right way. Because of compounding, the profit after four months is $(1+r)^4-1$, not $r+r^2+r^3+r^4$. To find the value of r that creates 100% profit after 4 months you need to solve $(1+r)^4-1=1$, which gives a value for r of about 19%.